# My orders in Magento 1.7 account sidebar

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have a problem with the Account details sidebar. I can suddenly no longer see the "my orders" element there.

Where are these items defined?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The My Orders menu item can be found inside the file

```
 /app/design/frontend/yourtheme/template/layout/sales.xml
```

Failing that go through the Magento fallback in your layout folder until you find sales.xml

Possibly an extension you've recently added has removed the My Orders links with XML.

Comment: Do you mean this: 

    <customer_account>
        <!-- Mage_Sales -->
        <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="sales"><name>orders</name><path>sales/order/history/</path><label>My Orders</label></action>
        </reference>

    </customer_account>

Comment: I removed every extension related to this. I can't get it to show up again. do you have any other suggestions?